# Multiple DropDown with similar options and each Drop down with a Dynamic child DropDown

Tags: javascript, html

There are 5 parent dropdown select box (1,2,3,4,5)  with similar options(A,B,C). Each  parent dropdown list has a dynamic child dropdown select box  with 2 options(true,false). Each options in parent dropdown can be selected twice with corresponding child options. If both the child options are selected for a particular parent dropdown then the parent dropdown should be removed in rest of  dropdown  select box . Kindly  suggest how to remove Selected options  using Javascript and HTML.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Please post your html structure. This at least gives people a starting place rather than having to code up your entire solution for you. Help us help you

Comment: Questions about code should contain code. I can't make any sense out of your words, but seeing code would speak for itself.